# Ruby on Rails, users can set their location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, location, maps

So I'm developing an web application using Ruby on Rails, and I want to find a way where the user, upon creating his account, may set his location. I was thinking about something like a google maps API for rails, where the user would select his place of living.

If anyone have any tips on that I'll be thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good [SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/nebirhos/geolocation-on-rails) that talks about enabling geolocation in your rails app. You can easily get the location of a user and set it up as their default using javascript.

Lets say you want to get the current location of a user and display it in your views:
First include the appropriate google maps api js library:

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>`

**views/index**

```
<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="error-message">
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Google Maps</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="location">
      <div class="loc longitude">
        <h3>Longitude</h3>
        <p id="longitude"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></p>
      </div>
      <div class="loc latitude">
        <h3>Latitude</h3>
        <p id="latitude"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 google-map-container">
        <div id="google-map">
          <h3>Map</h3>
          <div id="map_canvas">
            <div class="  ">
              <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div> <!-- /container -->

</html>
```

Now lets say you have two js files, one that fetches the user longitude and latitude and another that created and inserts a map based on the users location

**fetch_location.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = document.getElementById("latitude");
    var y = document.getElementById("longitude");
    // $('.vertical-align').hide();
  function getLocation() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            x.innerHTML =  position.coords.latitude.toFixed(4);
            y.innerHTML = position.coords.longitude.toFixed(4);

            insertMap(latitude,longitude);
        });

  }

  getLocation();
});
```

Then in **inser_map.js**

```
function insertMap(latitude, longitude) {

$('#map_canvas').html(initialize(latitude,longitude));

    function initialize(latitude,longitude){
   var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  }
}
```

The insertMap function will populate the div of id `map_canvas` with the map and a pin of the location of the user.

You can then use this information to persist the user's location to the db.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I've found this small tutorial that also helped me: https://binarapps.com/blog/integration-of-googlemaps-in-rails-4/